# How to select highlighted listbox item to add to textbox

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, selected

My code has a listbox filled with common small strings of text that the user can click to add to a texbox instead of manually typing them out.
It works in everyway except the previously selected item cannot be clicked again to add to textbox.

I've tried setting listbox.selected = -1 and listbox1.value ="" and when I do this the text is added twice and not unselected.
At one point I was able to make a button that just does listbox1.value = "" and it worked, but when I add it after my code it fails and does the double text thing.

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Click()
For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
If ListBox1.selected(i) Then
selecteditemtext = ListBox1.List(i)
End If
Next i
TextBox2.Text = TextBox2.Text & selecteditemtext & ", "
```

What I need it for the selected listbox item become unselected after being clicked so it can be clicked again if needed.

When I run this code line by line it works. but all together it adds the text twice.

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Click()
For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
If ListBox1.selected(i) Then
selecteditemtext = ListBox1.List(i)
End If
Next i
TextBox2.Text = TextBox2.Text & selecteditemtext & ", " 
call listdeselect
end sub

sub listdeselect()
sheet1.listbox1.value = ""
end sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have your solution :)

Control the deselection in the MouseUp event as shown below:

```
Private Sub ListBox1_MouseUp(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    ListBox1.ListIndex = -1
End Sub
```

As long as you don't interrupt the MouseUp event (such as with a MsgBox), this seems to work fine.

Sample code I have used is below:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    ListBox1.AddItem "asd"
    ListBox1.AddItem "sad"
    ListBox1.AddItem "dsa"
    ListBox1.AddItem "das"
End Sub

Private Sub ListBox1_Click()
    Sheets(1).Cells(1).Value = ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListIndex)
    'MsgBox "hi"   'notice this disrupts the MouseUp event...
End Sub

Private Sub ListBox1_MouseUp(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    ListBox1.ListIndex = -1
End Sub
```

I hope this resolves your issue,
Cheers